# React Best Practice: logic vs functions in JSX

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am wondering about best practices with JSX. So JSX lets you have logic in the html, which can vary from a map function, to conditional logic and more. But with simple and "small" logic bits, I am unsure.

What is best practice regarding this?

```
 getClassName = () => {
    return conditional
      ? "some class names hide"
      : "some class names";
  };

 <div
    className={ this.getClassName() }         
 />
```

vs

```
 <div
    className={
       this.state.conditional
          ? "some class names hide"
          : "some class names"
    }
 />
```

Comment: Functionally these are the same so mostly it will be personal preference. For simple ternary operators inlining them is usually ok, but if there's any _actual_ logic then it's probably better to put it in its own function, so you don't bloat the rendering function and you can edit the logic in its own space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your specific question there is no "right" way or a better practice. Do what feels natural for you.

For simple conditionals like the one you presented I usually go for the latter option

```
<div
    className={
       this.state.conditional
          ? "some class names hide"
          : "some class names"
    }
 />
```

Gives a more immediate knowledge of what is going to happen. If it involves more complex logic and more operations then go for a function.

Answer (score 2):

It is a pretty common practice to use logic bits in jsx.

I personally don't like it, as it tends to make render functions less readable (and can cause bugs when you don't see clearly what your code does with all the possible branching).
I prefer calling functions that'll handle the logic.

As for your example, I'd recommend using the classnames package (https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think using the `classnames` packages is the best practice. I think the render function should be pure and do not mix in too much logic.